# How do I play Youtube videos through links stored in my database in my react native app

Tags: youtube, react-native, video-player

I have Youtube video links stored in my database.

Is it possible to make a video player for playing videos through that links in react native application using expo?

Which npm library is best for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

you can play youtube videos in react native using:

[react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview) : just put your video url in the `source` props to play the video

[react-native-youtube](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube) : or use this component for a better user expirience

Comment: but sir react-native-youtube is not working with expo